# Which stations will be redeveloped by the Indian Railways in Amrit Bharat Scheme?

Tags: india, data-sources, transportation

The Indian Railway ministry has announced the [Amrit Bharat Scheme](https://pib.gov.in/PressReleasePage.aspx?PRID=1886884) for redevelopment of railway stations across India.

Which stations will be redeveloped exactly? Is there a list that I can check?

Comment: From what I understood, **all** railway stations in India are going to be upgraded. But it will be done slowly and they are still working on the long-term "master plan". Since there is a commercial aspect to this, they will logically be starting with the busiest stations in tier-1, tier-2, etc. cities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer.

The question was asked by various MPs in a recent lok sabha session.

Answer was given by the Ministry of Railways. The List can be found [here](https://pqals.nic.in/annex/1711/AS86.pdf). To summarize:

> 1275 stations have been selected based on the proposals
> received from Zonal Railways, stations located in major cities
> and towns.
> No time-frame can be indicated at this stage.

149 stations in Uttar Pradesh will be redeveloped, followed by 123 in Maharashtra (20+ in Mumbai City alone) and 94 in West Bengal.